# C - fscanf reading error

Tags: c, scanf

Just a heads up this is technically not a homework assignment.  It is not worth a grade, and it just for practice.  So do not think I am cheating to get a better grade.

Here is the function I am working in:

```
Car* readCars(char* filename) {
    FILE* fp = fopen( filename, "r" );

    if( fp == NULL ) {
        printf( "Error: Invalid File!" );
        exit(1);
    }

    Car cars[5];
    Car *carPtr;
    int i = 0;

    while( 1 ) {
        fscanf( fp, "%s %s %s %i", cars[i].color, cars[i].model, cars[i].brand, &cars[i].year );
        if( feof( fp ) ) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    carPtr = cars;

    fclose( fp );

    return carPtr;
}
```

Car struct:

```
typedef struct _car {
    char* color;
    char* model;
    char* brand;
    int year;
} Car;
```

At "return cars;" I am getting the "incompatible types when returning type 'struct Car *' when expecting 'Car'"

Here is where I am calling the function from main, and the declaration I have for the Car "object" in my mind.

```
Car *car;

car = readCars( carFileName );
```

1.) I am getting an error when scanning in from the file.

Comment: `Car readCars ()` returns a single car. `return cars` in function variable `cars` is an array

Comment: Perhaps `Car *readCars (char* filename)` ?

Comment: You declared a function returning `Car` then return an array of `Car`. Another problem is returning a pointer to a local variable invokes undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

No space for the string in structure `Car`.

```
typedef struct _car {
    // char* color;
    char color[20];
    int year;
} Car;

if (2 != fscanf(fp, "%19s%d", cars[i].color, &cars[i].year) {
  break;
}
```